# golang reflect доступ полям структуры

Tags: golang, struct

Есть такая структура:

```
type User struct{ID string}
u := &User{}
```

Как из `u.ID` получить название поля - «ID» не указывая что это «ID»?
Получение по индексу не подходит.

По индексу не подходит, потому что положение в структуре может быть изменено: в случае удаления одного из полей структуры нумерация нарушится. Вытащить, означает получить имя этого свойства, согласен формулировка не совсем корректная.

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, что конкретно вы имеете в виду под "вытащить «ID» не указывая что это «ID»", но поля можно также брать по индексу:

```
func f(v interface{}) {
    vv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    fmt.Println(vv.Elem().Field(0).Interface())
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/vIkVzHYM_a.

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор Go работает с адресами в памяти, для него нет "имен" в твоем представлении. Есть адрес, тип и значение. На этом все. 
Извлечь имена полей структуры ты можешь путем перебора по индексу, по другому никак.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "log"
)

type (
    User struct {
        ID string
        Name string
        FIO string
    }
)

func main() {
    user := &User{"IDsome","spouk","fio"}
    ShowStructure(user)
}

func ShowStructure(s interface{}) {
    a := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    numfield := reflect.ValueOf(s).Elem().NumField()
    if a.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        log.Fatal("wrong type struct")
    }
    for x := 0; x < numfield; x++ {
        fmt.Printf("Name field: `%s`  Type: `%s`\n", reflect.TypeOf(s).Elem().Field(x).Name,
            reflect.ValueOf(s).Elem().Field(x).Type())
    }
}
```